# How to resolve "local edit, incoming delete upon update" message

Tags: svn

When I do a `svn status .`, I get this:

```
!     C auto-complete-config.elc
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C auto-complete.elc
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C popup.elc
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C fuzzy.elc
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
```

basically, these files shouldn't be in the repository. A developer has removed them. Then, I think I did a `svn rm ...` after the fact by mistake (should've done `svn update .` instead).

So now, when I do `svn status .`, I get these tree conflict messages.

I found the doc [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html) but not sure how to “merge” it according to the doc.

How to get rid of them?

I think my working copy is in sync with the repository. Don't know why these messages shows. These files should be removed and are removed as far as I know everywhere. I tried `svn update .` and `svn revert .` but I still get this message when I do `svn status .`.

Comment: lesmana's answer also works for the message `"local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge"`

Answer (score 450, accepted):

Short version:

```
$ svn st
!  +  C foo
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C bar
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
$ touch foo bar
$ svn revert foo bar
$ rm foo bar
```

If the conflict is about directories instead of files then replace `touch` with `mkdir` and `rm` with `rm -r`.

---

Note: the same procedure also work for the following situation:

```
$ svn st
!     C foo
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
!     C bar
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
```

---

Long version:

This happens when you edit a file while someone else deleted the file and commited first. As a good svn citizen you do an update before a commit. Now you have a conflict. Realising that deleting the file is the right thing to do you delete the file from your working copy. Instead of being content svn now complains that the local files are missing and that there is a conflicting update which ultimately wants to see the files deleted. Good job svn.

Should `svn resolve` not work, for whatever reason, you can do the following:

Initial situation: Local files are missing, update is conflicting.

```
$ svn st
!  +  C foo
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C bar
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
```

Recreate the conflicting files:

```
$ touch foo bar
```

If the conflict is about directories then replace `touch` with `mkdir`.

New situation: Local files to be added to the repository (yeah right, svn, whatever you say), update still conflicting.

```
$ svn st
A  +  C foo
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
A  +  C bar
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
```

Revert the files to the state svn likes them (that means deleted):

```
$ svn revert foo bar
```

New situation: Local files not known to svn, update no longer conflicting.

```
$ svn st
?       foo
?       bar
```

Now we can delete the files:

```
$ rm foo bar
```

If the conflict is about directories then replace `rm` with `rm -r`.

svn no longer complains:

```
$ svn st
```

Done.

Comment: This also works when the conflict is for a Directory. Instead of **touch foo bar** do **mkdir foo** and **mkdir bar**. Everything else is the same.

Comment: you can use `svn st | grep ! | cut -f 7 -d' ' | xargs touch` as one liner for touching all the missing files

Comment: Remember for directories also do `rm -r foo bar` (or `rmdir foo bar` on Windows or if you like Windows).

Answer (score 161):

Try to resolve the conflict using

```
svn resolve --accept=working PATH
```

Comment: thanks. that seems to be the right solution. (didn't know about "resolve" option before. I marked it as answer. Though, for some reason didn't work for me, probably because my working copy tree has been corrupted or whatnot... in the end i resolved it by just deleting the dir and do a update.

Comment: It didn't work for me initially, so I checked out another copy of the svn branch in a temporary folder. Then I deleted the PATH causing conflict and committed the changes.

After that I went back to my original copy and ran this command. It worked with the message "Resolved conflicted state of PATH"
This works, thanks :)

Comment: My understanding is that it would not have mattered if the original was deleted or not in the repository, because "resolve" works only on the working copy.

Answer (score 21):

I just got this same issue and I found that

```
$ svn revert foo bar
```

solved the problem.

svn resolve did not work for me:

```
$ svn st
!  +  C foo
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C bar
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update

$ svn resolve --accept working
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Not enough arguments provided

$ svn resolve --accept working .

$ svn st
!  +  C foo
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
!  +  C bar
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update

$ svn resolve --accept working foo
Resolved conflicted state of 'foo'

$ svn st
!  +    foo
!  +  C bar
      >   local edit, incoming delete upon update
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't made any changes inside the conflicted directory, you can also `rm -rf conflicts_in_here/` and then `svn up`. This worked for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can force to revert your local directory to svn.

```
 svn revert -R your_local_path
```

Comment: Thanks, also helped me to resolve `A  +  C path/to/dir` and `>   local dir edit, incoming dir delete or move upon update`

Answer (score 0):

So you can just revert the file that you deleted but remember, If you are working on any type of project with a set project file (like iOS), reverting the file will add it to your system folder structure but not your project file structure. additional steps may be required if you are in this case

Answer (score 0):

This issue often happens when we try to *merge* another branch changes from a wrong directory.

Ex:

```
Branch2\Branch1_SubDir$ svn merge -rStart:End Branch1
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   Merging at wrong location
```

A conflict that gets thrown on its execution is :

```
Tree conflict on 'Branch1_SubDir'
   > local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge
```

And when you select **q** to *quit resolution*, you get status as:

```
 M      .
!     C Branch1_SubDir
      >   local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge
!     C Branch1_AnotherSubDir
      >   local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge
```

which clearly means that the merge contains changes related to `Branch1_SubDir` and `Branch1_AnotherSubDir`, and these folders couldn't be found inside `Branch1_SubDir`(obviously a directory can't be inside itself).

**How to avoid this issue at first place:**

```
Branch2$ svn merge -rStart:End Branch1
 ^^^^
Merging at root location
```

The **simplest fix** for this issue that worked for me :

```
svn revert -R .
```